# Java program converting user input string representing binary number to decimal

Tags: java, binary, decimal

Java Program. Eclipse IDE most recent. Java 17.0.1.

The program should prompt user a string representing a binary number. word must be 8 digits or less and must contain only 1s and 0s. If word is not 8 digits or less program should prompt user to make it such. If input does not contain only 1s and 0s, program should prompt user to only include 1s and 0s. I will post code that I have so far, I know that it is incomplete but I'm pretty much frozen where I'm at not sure where to go with it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isValid=false;
        String bin = "";
        int power =0;
        int x=0;
        long decimal = 0;
        int answer=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//create input method
        do {        
            System.out.println("Please enter a binary number: ");//prompt user for binary number
            bin = sc.nextLine();//bin equals input 
            if(bin.length()<=8) {//if length is 8 or less digits
                for(int i =bin.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {//for the char at index i
                    if(((bin.charAt(i)=='1'))||(bin.charAt(i)=='0')){
                        isValid=true;   
                        x=bin.indexOf(i);
                        power++;//power increase by 1 for each digit 
                        decimal=(long)Math.pow(2,power);
    
                        System.out.println("The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: " + decimal);
                        break;
                    }else
                        isValid=false;
                        System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter binary number containing only 1s and 0s:");
                }
            }else 
                System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter binary number with 8 or less digits: ");
        }
        while(isValid=true);
    }
}
```

Output I get is:

```
Please enter a binary number: 
0101
The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 1
Please enter a binary number: 
1111
The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 2
Please enter a binary number: 
1111111
The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 4
Please enter a binary number: 
111
The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 8
Please enter a binary number: 
11
The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 16
Please enter a binary number: 
01
The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 32
Please enter a binary number:
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: You're printing a result inside your `for` loop, then exiting the loop.  That means you're just printing a value for the last digit of your input.  But you should be using that `for` loop to traverse your entire number, instead of breaking out of it.  Then print your result _after_ all the iterations of the `for` loop are complete.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an assignment, because you can do `Integer.parseInt(<input>, 2)` to parse a string as a binary number.

Comment: Also, you will want to start isValid off as true, and only switch it to false if you find an invalid number, otherwise it will remain true as long as the last character is valid (you only check isValid after parsing the whole number)

Comment: did you try [debugging](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php)?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the code for you.

- The result of `Math.pow()` is added to `decimal` when the digit is one, and moved this line before `power++` because if the last digit is 1 it would have a value of 1 but the original code would add 2. 2 to the power of 0 is 1, so not incrementing power before the first pow is correct.
- Moved `break` to the `else` condition and moved the output of the decimal number to be the last line of the loop.
- Added missing curly brackets to both of the `else` clauses. With `break` removed, the `Invalid number` is always printed.
- Initialize `decimal` and `power` to zero at beginning of loop. Without setting these to zero, subsequent numbers converted give the wrong output.
- Only prints the result if it is valid.
- Go to next iteration with `continue` if number is more than 8 digits.

```java
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean isValid=false;
            String bin = "";
            int power =0;
            int x=0;
            long decimal = 0;
            int answer=0;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//create input method
            do {        
                System.out.println("Please enter a binary number: ");//prompt user for binary number
                decimal = 0;
                power = 0;
                bin = sc.nextLine();//bin equals input 
                if(bin.length()<=8) {//if length is 8 or less digits
                    for(int i =bin.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {//for the char at index i
                        if(((bin.charAt(i)=='1'))||(bin.charAt(i)=='0')){
                            isValid=true;   
                            x=bin.indexOf(i);
                            if(bin.charAt(i) == '1'){
                                decimal+=(long)Math.pow(2,power);
                            }
                            power++;//power increase by 1 for each digit 
        
                        }else {
                            isValid=false;
                            System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter binary number containing only 1s and 0s:");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number. Please enter binary number with 8 or less digits: ");
                    continue;
                }
                if (isValid) {
                    System.out.println("The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: " + decimal);
                }
            }
            while(isValid=true);
        }
```

Output:

```
Please enter a binary number:
11000110
The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 198 
Please enter a binary number:
10100010
The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 162
88437640
Invalid number. Please enter binary number containing only 1s and 0s:
Please enter a binary number:
123456789
Invalid number. Please enter binary number with 8 or less digits:
Please enter a binary number:
11111111                                                                                                                The binary number you entered converted to decimal is: 255                                                              Please enter a binary number:  
^C
```

Comment: your code would not error if you entered the string "88437640" for example, even though it should. It will also print the decimal even though the value is invalid.